# Can ApiResponse of swagger use HttpStatus in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

When using spring boot with swagger, I find the number and the message are hardcoded before `@GetMapping`

```java
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found")
```

Can I use something like

```java
@ApiResponse(response = HttpStatus.OK)
```

and `code` and `message` take `HttpStatus.OK` ?
so I don't have to write message and code?

I found I can use

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
```

and it shows up in swagger doc, but I cannot use several like the following

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

**EDIT:**
My swagger version is 2.9.2,
and I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Swagger annotations are you using?

Basically, referring to documentation there are 6 possible elements that can be used inside @ApiResponse (Swagger-Core v1.5.0): **code, message, reference, response, responseContainer, responseHeaders**. And 5 possible elements in Swagger-Core v.2.0.0-RC3: **content, description, headers, links, response code**.

So to summarize, it's not possible to set only a response value, but generate both: response code and message.

Also, in version 1.5.0, **code and message** elements are required. So you can't use only one of them.